# How to implement different reward for rewaredvideo ads

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, admob

I have fortune wheel in my game which can be played on watching video ad. this wheel can give 4 type of rewards.(4 diamond, 8 diamonds, jackpot, bonus level) now i don't know how to get this done. along this i also have double coin button in my each level which also triggered on watching ad.

here is my admanager script which is linked to double coin button from which i call the ShowRewardedVideo()

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using admob;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class AdManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static AdManager _instance;

    public static AdManager Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                _instance = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<AdManager>();
            }

            return _instance;
        }
    }
    public Admob ad;
    string appID = "";
    string bannerID = "";
    string interstitialID = "";
    string videoID = "";
    string nativeBannerID = "";

    void Awake()
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        //Replace with your IDs here. These are test ids for you to check if the ads are implemented properly or not
#if UNITY_IOS
                 appID="ca-app-pub-6533984286287209~3970651947";
                 bannerID="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111";
                 interstitialID="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712";
                 videoID="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917";
                 nativeBannerID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2247696110";
#elif UNITY_ANDROID
        appID = "ca-app-pub-1147416347412616~8130084612";
        bannerID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111";
        interstitialID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712";
        videoID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917";
        nativeBannerID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2247696110";
#endif
        AdProperties adProperties = new AdProperties();
        adProperties.isTesting=true;
        adProperties.isAppMuted=false;
        adProperties.isUnderAgeOfConsent=false;
        adProperties.appVolume=100;
        ad = Admob.Instance();
        ad.bannerEventHandler += onBannerEvent;
        ad.interstitialEventHandler += onInterstitialEvent;
        ad.rewardedVideoEventHandler += onRewardedVideoEvent;
       // ad.rewardedVideoEventHandler -= onRewardedVideoEvent;


        ad.initSDK(appID,adProperties);//reqired,adProperties can been null
        ad.loadInterstitial(interstitialID);
        
        InvokeRepeating("CacheVideoAd", 1, 5);
        
    }

    void CacheVideoAd()
    {
        if (!ad.isRewardedVideoReady())
        {
            ad.loadRewardedVideo(videoID);
            ad.rewardedVideoEventHandler -= onRewardedVideoEvent;

        }
    }

    IEnumerator LoadGameScene()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
        SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync("MainMenu");
    }

    public bool IsAdReady()
    {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        return false;
#endif
        return ad.isRewardedVideoReady();
        ad.rewardedVideoEventHandler -= onRewardedVideoEvent;

    }

    public void ShowInterstitial()
    {
        //To give a call back to this use the code below
        //AdManager.Instance.ShowInterstitial();
#if UNITY_ANDROID
        print("touch inst button -------------");
        try
        {
            if (ad.isInterstitialReady())
            {
                ad.showInterstitial();
            }
            else
            {
                ad.loadInterstitial(interstitialID);
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            print(e);
        }
#endif
    }
    public void ShowBanner()
    {
        //To give a call back to this use the code below
        //AdManager.Instance.ShowBanner();
        Admob.Instance().showBannerRelative(bannerID, AdSize.SMART_BANNER, AdPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER);
    }

    public void DestroyBanner()
    {
        //To give a call back to this use the code below
        //AdManager.Instance.DestroyBanner();
        Admob.Instance().removeBanner();
    }

    public void ShowRewardedVideo()
    {
        //To give a call back to this use the code below
        //AdManager.Instance.ShowRewardedVideo();
        Debug.Log("touch video button -------------");
        if (ad.isRewardedVideoReady())
        {
            ad.showRewardedVideo();

        }
        else
        {
            ad.loadRewardedVideo(videoID);
            ad.rewardedVideoEventHandler -= onRewardedVideoEvent;

        }
    }

    void onInterstitialEvent(string eventName, string msg)
    {
        Debug.Log("handler onAdmobEvent---" + eventName + "   " + msg);
        if (eventName == AdmobEvent.onAdLoaded)
        {
            // Admob.Instance().showInterstitial();
        }
    }
    void onBannerEvent(string eventName, string msg)
    {
        Debug.Log("handler onAdmobBannerEvent---" + eventName + "   " + msg);
    }
    void onRewardedVideoEvent(string eventName, string msg)
    {
        Debug.Log("handler onRewardedVideoEvent---" + eventName + "  rewarded: " + msg);
        if(eventName == AdmobEvent.onRewarded)
        {
            //Add reward condition here
            SaveManager.Instance.DiamondReward();
            ad.rewardedVideoEventHandler -= onRewardedVideoEvent;
            Debug.Log("diamond reward which is (4 Diamonds)");
        }
    }
}
```

And this is SpinManager script attached to spinner wheel

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;

public class SpiningManager : MonoBehaviour {

    int randVal;
    private float timeInterval;
    private bool isCoroutine;
    private int finalAngle;

    public Text winText;
    public int section;
    float totalAngle;
    public string[] PrizeName;
    // Use this for initialization
    private MenuScene g;
    private void Start () {

        isCoroutine = true;
        totalAngle = 360 / section;

        g = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<MenuScene>();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void Update () {
        float xRotate = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        if (xRotate == 1 && isCoroutine) {
            StartCoroutine (Spin ());
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator Spin(){

        isCoroutine = false;
        randVal = Random.Range (80, 150);

        timeInterval = Time.deltaTime*2;

        for (int i = 0; i < randVal; i++) {

            transform.Rotate (0, 0, (totalAngle/2)); //Start Rotate 


            //To slow Down Wheel
            if (i > Mathf.RoundToInt (randVal * .2f))//0.2f
                timeInterval = 0.5f*Time.deltaTime;
            if (i > Mathf.RoundToInt (randVal * .5f))//0.2f
                timeInterval = 1f*Time.deltaTime;
            if (i > Mathf.RoundToInt (randVal * .7f))//0.2f
                timeInterval = 1.5f*Time.deltaTime;
            if (i > Mathf.RoundToInt (randVal * .8f))//0.2f
                timeInterval = 2f*Time.deltaTime;
            if (i > Mathf.RoundToInt (randVal * .9f))
                timeInterval = 2.5f*Time.deltaTime;

            yield return new WaitForSeconds (timeInterval);

        }

        if (Mathf.RoundToInt (transform.eulerAngles.z) % totalAngle != 0) //when the indicator stop between 2 numbers,it will add aditional step 
            transform.Rotate (0, 0, totalAngle/2);
        
        finalAngle = Mathf.RoundToInt (transform.eulerAngles.z);//round off euler angle of wheel value

        print (finalAngle);

        //Prize check
        for (int i = 0; i < section; i++) {

            if (finalAngle == i * totalAngle)
            {
                winText.text = PrizeName[i];
                if(winText.text == "BONUS LEVEL")
                {
                    Debug.Log("Play Bonus Level");
                }
                else if(winText.text == "DIAMONDS X8")
                {
                    Debug.Log("Give DIAMONDS X8");

                }
                else if (winText.text == "DIAMONDS X4")
                {
                    Debug.Log("Give DIAMONDS X4");

                }
                else if (winText.text == "JACKPOT")
                {
                    Debug.Log("Give JACKPOT");                      
                }
            }
        }
        isCoroutine = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather use `enum` instead of strings, in general use `switch-case`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**AdManager.cs:**

```
void onRewardedVideoEvent(string eventName, string msg)
    {
        Debug.Log("handler onRewardedVideoEvent---" + eventName + "  rewarded: " + msg);
        if(eventName == AdmobEvent.onRewarded)
        {
        
            Switch(SpiningManager.currentRewardType)
            {
            case SpiningManager.RewardType.PLAYBONUSLEVEL:
            //Reward for Bonus 
            break;
            
            case SpiningManager.RewardType.DIAMONDSX8:
            //Reward for DIAMONDSX8 
            break;
            
            case SpiningManager.RewardType.DIAMONDSX4:
            //Reward for DIAMONDSX4 
             SaveManager.Instance.DiamondReward();
            break;
            
            case SpiningManager.RewardType.JACKPOT:
            //Reward for JACKPOT 
            break;
            
            }
        
        
            //Add reward condition here
           
            ad.rewardedVideoEventHandler -= onRewardedVideoEvent;
           
        }
    }
```

Comment: from where to call showrewardedvideo () function. i tried it in various ways the ad did played but i didn't got reward.

Comment: ad.rewardedVideoEventHandler -= onRewardedVideoEvent;   this line will unsubscribe event call when video is rewarded. you should not do that each time you load rewarded video you can subscribe with += as above ,   InvokeRepeating("CacheVideoAd", 1, 5); this is wrong way to Request rewarded video ads , you should do it after init admob, and then load again in rewarded event or close event or you can also load it in load fail event.

Comment: InvokeRepeating("CacheVideoAd", 1, 5);  this line will load video multiple time even if you already catched. you should do like catch -> show -> catch again ->  if not loaded then catch

Answer (score 0):

### SpiningManager.cs:

```
public enum RewardType
{PLAYBONUSLEVEL=0,
DIAMONDSX8,
DIAMONDSX4=2,
JACKPOT=3};  
public static RewardType currentRewardType;

    for (int i = 0; i < section; i++) 
    {

        if (finalAngle == i * totalAngle)
        {
            winText.text = PrizeName[i];
            if(winText.text == "BONUS LEVEL")
            {
                currentRewardType= RewardType.PLAYBONUSLEVEL;
                Debug.Log("Play Bonus Level");
            }
            else if(winText.text == "DIAMONDS X8")
            {
            currentRewardType= RewardType.DIAMONDSX8;
                Debug.Log("Give DIAMONDS X8");

            }
            else if (winText.text == "DIAMONDS X4")
            {
            currentRewardType= RewardType.DIAMONDSX4;
                Debug.Log("Give DIAMONDS X4");

            }
            else if (winText.text == "JACKPOT")
            {
            currentRewardType= RewardType.JACKPOT;
                Debug.Log("Give JACKPOT");                      
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by setting playerprefs key for each reward and checking if the playerprefs key is available to get reward in onrewarded() function and after claiming i delete the key.